# Windows Phone, loading resources from directory

Tags: resources, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, resourcedictionary

I've got the following folder structure in the project:

```
Style
    MainStyles.xaml
MainPage.xaml
```

Inside MainPage.xaml I try to load resources from MainStyles:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style\MainStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
WinRT information: Failed to assign to property '%0'. [Line: 13 Position: 37]

Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
```

Line 13 and position 37 is the exact place of `Source="...`. If I move resources to the same directory as MainPage and remove the directory, everything works.

By the way, Visual Studio designer does not complain about lacking resources and use them correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try doing two things: 1) Use a forward slash, '`/`'. 2) Add a leading forward slash, '`/Style/MainStyles.xaml`'.

Comment: @NateDiamond Forward slash works. That's weird :) Thanks! You may post it as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a forward slash when setting the `Source` of a `ResourceDictionary`.

I.e. `Style/MainStyles.xaml`